Updating a fitted R mgcv::bam model reports an "invalid type (closure)..." error
I am attempting to "bam.update" my fitted mgcv::bam model that uses the "weights" argument and getting the following error:
Error in model.frame.default(gp$fake.formula, data, weights = weights,  : 
  invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'

I could not fix this myself so am dropping the problem here. Here is an example code generating exactly the same error I am getting with a much larger model:
library(data.table)
library(mgcv)

mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)

# adding arbitrary "model_weigts"
set.seed(55)
mtcars[, model_weigts := abs(rnorm(nrow(mtcars)))]

# split the dataset
mtcars_1 <- mtcars[1:20,]
mtcars_2 <- mtcars[21:32,]

# an arbitrary model formula 
formula_c <- formula(mpg ~ s(wt) + s(hp))

# fit the initial model to mtcars_1 and attempt to update it with mtcars_2
model_initial <- mgcv::bam(formula_c, data = mtcars_1, weights = model_weigts)
model_updated <- mgcv::bam.update(model_initial, data = mtcars_2)

sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Australia/Adelaide
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mgcv_1.9-1        nlme_3.1-164      data.table_1.15.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.3 Matrix_1.6-5   splines_4.3.3  grid_4.3.3     lattice_0.22-5


This should probably be a comment, but I can't reproduce your problem
Actually I can (I thought you loaded mtcars in your example and you didn't so my test when I reset after my checks didn't actually reset to a clean mtcars.
But that also points to the solution. Take Simon literally in terms of what he writes in ?bam.update:

Must include a weights column if the original fit was weighted

I can get this to work if I set up my model to use weights instead of model_weigts [sic]:
r$> library(data.table) 
    library(mgcv) 
     
    mtcars <- data.table(mtcars) 
     
    # adding arbitrary "model_weigts" 
    set.seed(55) 
    mtcars[, weights := abs(rnorm(nrow(mtcars)))] 
     
    # split the dataset 
    mtcars_1 <- mtcars[1:20,] 
    mtcars_2 <- mtcars[21:32,] 
     
    # an arbitrary model formula  
    formula_c <- formula(mpg ~ s(wt) + s(hp)) 
     
    # fit the initial model to mtcars_1 and attempt to update it with mtcars_2 
    model_initial <- mgcv::bam(formula_c, data = mtcars_1, weights =  weights) 
    model_updated <- mgcv::bam.update(model_initial, data = mtcars_2)           
r$>

Note no error. And I see
r$> model_updated$weights                                                       
 [1] 0.120139084 1.812376850 0.151582984 1.119221005 0.001908206 1.188518494
 [7] 0.505343855 0.099234393 0.305353199 0.198409703 0.048910950 0.843233767
[13] 2.075270771 0.360763148 0.637689661 0.366278030 2.355363898 1.093377235
[19] 0.285841001 0.993657777 1.519271950 1.497117849 0.819615308 1.066050411
[25] 0.733755906 0.960343958 0.692180983 1.405998395 1.633538987 0.261830993
[31] 1.564754415 0.314589303
r$> mtcars_1$weights                                                            
 [1] 0.120139084 1.812376850 0.151582984 1.119221005 0.001908206 1.188518494
 [7] 0.505343855 0.099234393 0.305353199 0.198409703 0.048910950 0.843233767
[13] 2.075270771 0.360763148 0.637689661 0.366278030 2.355363898 1.093377235
[19] 0.285841001 0.993657777
r$> mtcars_2$weights                                                            
 [1] 1.5192720 1.4971178 0.8196153 1.0660504 0.7337559 0.9603440 0.6921810
 [8] 1.4059984 1.6335390 0.2618310 1.5647544 0.3145893
r$> all.equal(model_updated$weights, c(mtcars_1$weights, mtcars_2$weights))     
[1] TRUE

so bam() updated the fit to include the new observations, using their weights, in addition to the original data and weights.
This is with:
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
 os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu
 ui       X11
 language en_GB:en
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8
 ctype    en_GB.UTF-8
 tz       Europe/Copenhagen
 date     2024-04-18
 pandoc   2.5 @ /usr/bin/pandoc

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cli           3.6.2   2023-12-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.2)
 data.table  * 1.15.4  2024-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.3)
 lattice       0.22-6  2024-03-20 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.3)
 Matrix        1.6-5   2024-01-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.2)
 mgcv        * 1.9-1   2023-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.3)
 nlme        * 3.1-164 2023-11-27 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.2)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.3.0)

 [1] /home/au690221/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3
 [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
 [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
 [4] /usr/lib/R/library

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


this is an unusual but effective solution which also works for my much larger model.

If weights are supplied to the initial bam() then bam.update() expects weights for the 'new data'; from the docs: "Must include a weights column if the original fit was weighted and a AR.start column if AR.start was non NULL in original fit."
Not sure if this is an option, but maybe you could alter the source code of the bam.update() function to make the weights for the new data a constant value (e.g. "1"):
library(data.table)
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.9-1. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)

# adding arbitrary "model_weigts"
set.seed(55)
mtcars$model_weigts <- abs(rnorm(nrow(mtcars)))

# split the dataset
mtcars_1 <- mtcars[1:20,]
mtcars_2 <- mtcars[21:32,]

# an arbitrary model formula 
formula_c <- formula(mpg ~ s(wt) + s(hp))

# fit the initial model to mtcars_1 and attempt to update it with mtcars_2
model_initial <- mgcv::bam(formula_c, data = mtcars_1, weights = model_weigts)

bam.update.modified <- function(b, data, chunk.size = 10000) 
{
  if (is.null(b$qrx)) {
    stop("Model can not be updated")
  }
  gp <- interpret.gam(b$formula)
  cnames <- names(b$coefficients)
  AR.start <- NULL
  getw <- "(weights)" %in% names(b$model)
  getARs <- "(AR.start)" %in% names(b$model)
  dummy_wt <<- rep(1, nrow(data))
  if (getw && getARs) {
    mf <- model.frame(gp$fake.formula, data, weights = dummy_wt, 
                      AR.start = AR.start, xlev = b$xlev, na.action = b$NA.action)
    w <- mf[["(weights)"]]
  }
  else if (getw) {
    
    mf <- model.frame(gp$fake.formula, data, weights = dummy_wt, 
                      xlev = b$xlev, na.action = b$NA.action)
    w <- mf[["(weights)"]]
  }
  else if (getARs) {
    mf <- model.frame(gp$fake.formula, data, AR.start = AR.start, 
                      xlev = b$xlev, na.action = b$NA.action)
    w <- rep(1, nrow(mf))
  }
  else {
    mf <- model.frame(gp$fake.formula, data, xlev = b$xlev, 
                      na.action = b$NA.action)
    w <- rep(1, nrow(mf))
  }
  X <- predict(b, newdata = mf, type = "lpmatrix", na.action = b$NA.action)
  rownames(X) <- NULL
  b$model <- rbind(b$model, mf)
  off.col <- attr(attr(b$model, "terms"), "offset")
  if (is.null(off.col)) 
    offset <- rep(0, nrow(mf))
  else offset <- mf[, off.col]
  y <- mf[, attr(attr(b$model, "terms"), "response")] - offset
  b$G$y <- c(b$G$y, y)
  b$G$offset <- c(b$G$offset, offset)
  b$G$w <- c(b$G$w, w)
  b$G$n <- nrow(b$model)
  n <- b$G$n
  w <- sqrt(w)
  if (b$AR1.rho != 0) {
    rho <- b$AR1.rho
    ld <- 1/sqrt(1 - rho^2)
    sd <- -rho * ld
    wy <- c(b$yX.last[1], w * y)
    wX <- rbind(b$yX.last[-1], w * X)
    m <- nrow(wX)
    b$yX.last <- c(wy[m], wX[m, ])
    row <- c(1, rep(1:m, rep(2, m))[-c(1, 2 * m)])
    weight <- c(1, rep(c(sd, ld), m - 1))
    stop <- c(1, 1:(m - 1) * 2 + 1)
    if (!is.null(mf$"(AR.start)")) {
      ii <- which(mf$"(AR.start)" == TRUE)
      if (length(ii) > 0) {
        if (ii[1] == 1) 
          ii <- ii[-1]
        weight[ii * 2 - 2] <- 0
        weight[ii * 2 - 1] <- 1
      }
    }
    wX <- rwMatrix(stop, row, weight, wX)[-1, ]
    wy <- rwMatrix(stop, row, weight, wy)[-1]
    b$qrx <- mgcv:::qr_update(wX, wy, b$qrx$R, b$qrx$f, b$qrx$y.norm2)
  }
  else {
    b$qrx <- mgcv:::qr_update(w * X, w * y, b$qrx$R, b$qrx$f, b$qrx$y.norm2)
  }
  rss.extra <- b$qrx$y.norm2 - sum(b$qrx$f^2)
  if (b$method == "GCV" || b$method == "UBRE") 
    method <- "GCV.Cp"
  else method <- b$method
  if (method == "GCV.Cp") {
    if (b$method == "GCV") 
      scale <- -1
    else scale = b$sig2
    fit <- magic(b$qrx$f, b$qrx$R, b$sp, b$G$S, b$G$off, 
                 L = b$G$L, lsp0 = b$G$lsp0, rank = b$G$rank, H = b$G$H, 
                 C = matrix(0, 0, ncol(b$qrx$R)), gamma = b$gamma, 
                 scale = scale, gcv = (scale <= 0), extra.rss = rss.extra, 
                 n.score = n)
    post <- magic.post.proc(b$qrx$R, fit, b$qrx$f * 0 + 
                              1)
    b$y <- b$G$y
    b$offset <- b$G$offset
    b$prior.weights <- b$weights <- b$G$w
  }
  else if (method == "fREML") {
    um <- mgcv:::Sl.Xprep(b$Sl, b$qrx$R)
    lsp0 <- log(b$sp)
    log.phi <- log(b$sig2)
    fit <- mgcv:::fast.REML.fit(um$Sl, um$X, b$qrx$f, rho = lsp0, 
                         L = b$G$L, rho.0 = b$G$lsp0, log.phi = log.phi, 
                         phi.fixed = !b$scale.estimated, rss.extra = rss.extra, 
                         nobs = n, Mp = um$Mp, nt = 1, gamma = b$gamma)
    if (b$scale.estimated) 
      scale <- -1
    else scale = b$sig2
    res <- mgcv:::Sl.postproc(b$Sl, fit, um$undrop, b$qrx$R, cov = TRUE, 
                       scale = scale, L = b$g$L)
    object <- list(coefficients = res$beta, edf = res$edf, 
                   edf1 = res$edf1, edf2 = res$edf2, gcv.ubre = fit$reml, 
                   hat = res$hat, outer.info = list(iter = fit$iter, 
                                                    message = fit$conv), optimizer = "fast-REML", 
                   rank = ncol(um$X), Ve = res$Ve, Vp = res$Vp, Vc = res$Vc, 
                   db.drho = fit$d1b, scale.estimated = scale <= 0)
    if (scale <= 0) {
      nsp <- length(fit$rho)
      object$sig2 <- object$scale <- exp(fit$rho[nsp])
      object$sp <- exp(fit$rho[-nsp])
      nsp <- length(fit$rho.full)
      object$full.sp <- exp(fit$rho.full[-nsp])
    }
    else {
      object$sig2 <- object$scale <- scale
      object$sp <- exp(fit$rho)
      object$full.sp <- exp(fit$rho.full)
    }
    if (b$AR1.rho != 0) {
      df <- if (getARs) 
        sum(b$model$"(AR.start)")
      else 1
      object$gcv.ubre <- object$gcv.ubre - (n - df) * 
        log(ld)
    }
    b$G$X <- b$qrx$R
    b$G$dev.extra <- rss.extra
    b$G$pearson.extra <- rss.extra
    b$G$n.true <- n
    b$y <- b$G$y
    b$offset <- b$G$offset
    b$prior.weights <- b$weights <- b$G$w
  }
  else {
    y <- b$G$y
    w <- b$G$w
    offset <- b$G$offset
    b$G$y <- b$qrx$f
    b$G$w <- b$G$y * 0 + 1
    b$G$X <- b$qrx$R
    b$G$n <- length(b$G$y)
    b$G$offset <- b$G$y * 0
    b$G$dev.extra <- rss.extra
    b$G$pearson.extra <- rss.extra
    b$G$n.true <- n
    if (b$scale.estimated) 
      scale <- -1
    else scale = b$sig2
    in.out <- list(sp = b$sp, scale = b$reml.scale)
    object <- gam(G = b$G, method = method, gamma = b$gamma, 
                  scale = scale, in.out = in.out)
    if (b$AR1.rho != 0) {
      df <- if (getARs) 
        sum(b$model$"(AR.start)")
      else 1
      object$gcv.ubre <- object$gcv.ubre - (n - df) * 
        log(ld)
    }
    b$offset <- b$G$offset <- offset
    b$prior.weights <- b$weights <- b$G$w <- w
    b$G$n <- n
    b$y <- b$G$y <- y
  }
  if (method == "GCV.Cp") {
    b$coefficients <- fit$b
    b$edf <- post$edf
    b$edf1 <- post$edf1
    b$full.sp <- fit$sp.full
    b$gcv.ubre <- fit$score
    b$hat <- post$hat
    b$mgcv.conv <- fit$gcv.info
    b$optimizer = "magic"
    b$rank <- fit$gcv.info$rank
    b$Ve <- post$Ve
    b$Vp <- post$Vb
    b$sig2 <- b$scale <- fit$scale
    b$sp <- fit$sp
  }
  else {
    b$coefficients <- object$coefficients
    b$edf <- object$edf
    b$edf1 <- object$edf1
    b$full.sp <- object$sp.full
    b$gcv.ubre <- object$gcv.ubre
    b$hat <- object$hat
    b$outer.info <- object$outer.info
    b$rank <- object$rank
    b$Ve <- object$Ve
    b$Vp <- object$Vp
    b$sig2 <- b$scale <- object$sig2
    b$sp <- object$sp
    if (b$AR1.rho != 0) {
      b$gcv.ubre <- b$gcv.ubre - (n - 1) * log(ld)
    }
  }
  b$R <- b$qrx$R
  b$G$X <- NULL
  b$linear.predictors <- as.numeric(predict.gam(b, newdata = b$model, 
                                                block.size = chunk.size))
  b$fitted.values <- b$linear.predictor
  b$residuals <- sqrt(b$family$dev.resids(b$y, b$fitted.values, 
                                          b$prior.weights)) * sign(b$y - b$fitted.values)
  b$deviance <- sum(b$residuals^2)
  b$aic <- b$family$aic(b$y, 1, b$fitted.values, b$prior.weights, 
                        b$deviance) + 2 * sum(b$edf)
  if (b$AR1.rho != 0) {
    df <- if (getARs) 
      sum(b$model$"(AR.start)")
    else 1
    b$aic <- b$aic + 2 * (n - df) * log(ld)
  }
  b$null.deviance <- sum(b$family$dev.resids(b$y, mean(b$y), 
                                             b$prior.weights))
  names(b$coefficients) <- names(b$edf) <- cnames
  b
}

model_updated <- bam.update.modified(model_initial, data = mtcars_2)
model_updated$model$`(weights)`
#>  [1] 0.120139084 1.812376850 0.151582984 1.119221005 0.001908206 1.188518494
#>  [7] 0.505343855 0.099234393 0.305353199 0.198409703 0.048910950 0.843233767
#> [13] 2.075270771 0.360763148 0.637689661 0.366278030 2.355363898 1.093377235
#> [19] 0.285841001 0.993657777 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000
#> [25] 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000 1.000000000
#> [31] 1.000000000 1.000000000

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0
Would this work for your use-case?

I like your example with "fixing" the problem. However, "bam.update" in your example would just ignore any weights when updating the initial (now modified) model, while this information is essential, and this is one of many updates. I am looking for the way to make "bam.update" working with this exact dataset, i.e. accounting for weights provided.

Yep - I thought that would be the case @MaxMoldovan - it doesn't really make sense to remove the weights but I posted an answer just in case it helped. Perhaps you could modify the source code to keep the weights and avoid the error?
